# I develop now login-register system, but got one error and don't know how to fix it

Tags: android

```
public class RegisterPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button _btnreg;
    EditText  _txtlname, _txtpass, _txtemail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page);

        openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        _txtlname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        _txtpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        _txtemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        _btnreg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

    }

    _btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String lname=_txtlname.getText().toString();

            String pass=_txtpass.getText().toString();
            String email=_txtemail.getText().toString();

            insertdata(lname,pass,email);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "register successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    public void insertdata(String lname, String pass, String email){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_2, lname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_4, pass);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_5, email);
        long id = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
}
```

This is code line that is with error. `setOnClickListener` is in red color and View v too, what is wrong there?

Comment: what is the type of _btnreg ?

Comment: that is register button

Comment: can you show us how did you define it ?

Comment: Button _btnreg;

Comment: _btnreg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

Comment: Missing closing bracket?

Comment: where closing bracket is missed?

Comment: set your `onClickListener()` in the `onCreate()` method after you initialize `_btnreg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on your updated question

you cant add listener to the button outside a method your listener should be inside a method so your code should be like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page);

    openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    _txtlname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    _txtpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    _txtemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    _btnreg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

_btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String lname=_txtlname.getText().toString();

        String pass=_txtpass.getText().toString();
        String email=_txtemail.getText().toString();

        insertdata(lname,pass,email);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "register successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: problem fixed. Thanks

Comment: please accept the answer if this answer helps you in order to help other people who  faces this problem too